# AUTO ARIMA MODEL to predict hourly data in python

Tags: python, time-series, arima, hour, pmdarima

```
     Datetime            Y
2013-07-01 00:00:00    216.0
2013-07-01 01:00:00    210.0
2013-07-01 02:00:00    225.0
2013-07-01 03:00:00    216.0
2013-07-01 04:00:00    222.0
```

My data is in above format with hourly frequency...
I would like to build a auto arima model to predict future out of sample values hourly frequency in python..

Can someone help me with the process ?

Comment: I think SO is only meant for problems you face while writing code ;)

Comment: could you please help me if possible

Comment: Start from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask